# Can't Setup Ratchet

Tags: zeromq, ratchet

I am trying to setup Ratchet on my system and have followed socketo.me 
I have done everything till installing ZMQ and React/Zmq and it was all successful.

But when I try to run `push-server.php`, the following error occurs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The provided listener was not a valid callable.' in C:\wamp\www\ratchet\vendor\evenement\evenement\src\Evenement\EventEmitter.php on line 21

 InvalidArgumentException: The provided listener was not a valid callable. in C:\wamp\www\ratchet\vendor\evenement\evenement\src\Evenement\EventEmitter.php on line 21
```

I have already set the PATH variable and enabled the php_zmq extension(I am on Windows using WAMP).
I have searched a lot but can't get through this problem, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you done  ?
You have changed the event to be called

```
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));
```

you have changed the onBlogEntry with a function  that you didn't declare in your pusher .. 
that's it